# Malloc a custom type and some other C questions

Tags: c, malloc

I'm currently making a game, in which I need a board, which has a bunch of "cells".

Data stored in those cells are read from a file which can only be read once in the whole program so I need to store those cells in the memory.

My question is, how can I do this? Let me explain what I have.

cell.h

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int row;
    unsigned int column;
    char value;
    bool initialCell;
    bool followsRules;
}Cell;
```

The file I'm reading is a board of size nxn, something like this:

```
9 7 8 5
0 9 6 4
9 7 5 6
0 2 1 6
```

So, as an example, the values of the first `Cell struct` would be the following

```
row = 1
column = 1
value = '9'
initialCell = true
followsRules = true
```

I know malloc returns a pointer to the memory allocated but, being a C beginner, I don't quite understand how can I put a Cell "into" that memory.

With the way I made the game, I have an array of rows for example, and each position of that array contains another array, in which each position points to a cell (basically a matrix of `Cell*`), my objective is to do something like this.

```
row[0][0]->value
```

Which gives me value inside the first cell of the first row.

So, how can make that `Cell*` point to the memory allocated for that Cell, and whats the best way to put the `Cell` into that memory.

Sorry for the long post, I have always worked with languages like Java or Python so memory allocation and management is a new thing for me.

Comment: you better to update question with sample piece of the file you need to read , to help us understand what would a Cell contains , char or float or int or string or  something more complex

Comment: Post has been updated!, thanks

Comment: you do not need malloc at this stage, i am working on an example

Comment: Thank you so much! The module that allocates the Cells and such is separated from the main() so i thought allocating memory was the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to guess the file layout of your board data. I will only address how you will allocate storage for this board in your program and access logically `board[m][n]`:

If you know in advance the value for `n`, the number of rows and columns, then you can statically allocate the storage for your board. Otherwise, you will dynamically allocate it with `malloc`. Either way, it would be most efficient to have a `Cell *` variable that is set to what you would think of as the address of `board[m][n]` and use that to access the members of the `Cell` structure so that this address does not have to be redundantly calculated.

Case 1 (static allocation of the board):

```
#define N 10
static Cell board[N * N];
```

Case 2 (dynamic allocation):

```
Cell *board = (Cell *)malloc(sizeof(Cell) * n * n); // where n is some value
```

To access a cell:

```
static Cell *getBoardCell(int row, int col)
{
    return board + row * N + col; // static case
    // or
    return board + row * n + col; // dynamic case
}

Cell *cellPtr getBoardCell(3, 6);
cellPtr->row = 3;
cellPtr->column = 6;
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, this is what I was looking for. In my case I used those rows and such because I actually made a custom array for some game things.
At the "lower layer" I basically have an Array of cells, so could I do something along the lines of:
`static Cell row[8]`
Then access by
`row[0]`

Answer (score 1):

sample code to read and print out a 4x4 file

save it as cell.c and compile with gcc or your own  compiler,
save your sample cell data in a file named "Cell"

```
gcc cell.c
./a.out
```

i coded with "one dimension" array of size n*n  ,
because one dimension array is simpler to iterate with, 
and you can always access cell by `cellArr[cellPerRow*rowNumber+ columnNumber].value`
instead of `row[rowNumber][columnNumber].value`

you would need to change the fscanf part to deal with different n*n cells,
i am leaving that work to you.
remember to assign values for `initialCell` and  `followsRules` according to your game rule

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct{
    unsigned int row;
    unsigned int column;
    char value;
    bool initialCell;
    bool followsRules;
}Cell;
const int cellPerRow = 4;

int main() {
    Cell *cellArr = (Cell *)malloc(cellPerRow * cellPerRow* sizeof(Cell));
    char fmt[1024];
    char cellRow[cellPerRow];
    int cellIndex = 0;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("Cell", "r");
    if(NULL == fp) {
        printf("The file was not opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    fmt[0] = '\0';
    for ( i=0;i<cellPerRow;i++)
        strcat(fmt,"%c ");
    fmt[strlen(fmt)-1] = '\n';
    while (EOF != fscanf(fp,fmt,
                     &cellRow[0],
                     &cellRow[1],
                     &cellRow[2],
                     &cellRow[3])
    ) {
        for ( i=0;i<cellPerRow;i++) {
            cellArr[cellIndex].row = cellIndex / cellPerRow;
            cellArr[cellIndex].column = i;
            cellArr[cellIndex].value = cellRow[i];
            cellIndex++;
        }
    }


    for (i=0;i<cellIndex;i++) {
       printf("%c ", cellArr[i].value);
       if (0 == (i+1) % cellPerRow) {
            printf("\n");
       }
    }
    free(cellArr);
}
```